# Regular Expression In Java Replace character and dot

Tags: regex

Trying write regexp in java to replace character and dot with "",my string is

String value = "a.employee";

in string i want to replace a. or b. or c. with "" using ReplaceAll method in java as  tried below regexp--

```
[a\.|b\.|c.]
```

but this is giving output as -

```
""""employee
```

but it should be like

```
""employee
```

can any one give me hint to solve this.

Comment: remove character class `[]` and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In character class everything is treated as single character. So in you regex

```
[a\.|b\.|c.]
```

It means match `a`or `.` or `|` or `b`or `.` or `|` or `c`or `.`. Final character class can be understood as intersection of all these characters. So in your character class, you finally have

```
[abc.|]
```

**NOTE** :- There is no need to escape `.` in character class. Inside character class `|` is literal pipe symbol and not the alternation that you are thinking.

Now, when you are using `replaceAll` on your string, it replaces your `a` with `""` and also `.` with `""`. Thus you are getting 4 double quotes.

You can use

```
System.out.println("a.employee".replaceAll("[abc][.]", "\"\""));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/qDIrgI)**